# how to copy a file in c byte by byte

Tags: c, pipe, fork, lseek

okay so I am studying C and in a textbook there is an exercise left for the reader leading up to this exercise the book explains that a file (or at least a regular file) is simply an array of bytes. it is my understanding that in linux each block is 512 bytes but when you read a file into a file descriptor then the program automatically loads up the entire file potentially correct?
the book goes over the Linux system calls `read, write, and lseek` (some basic low-level calls).

now the goal is like i said to copy a file byte by byte to some random new file. pseudo-code will be perfectly acceptable. In any case it is my understanding that you need

My understanding is that the build would go something like this:

```
#include <all of the req'd headers>

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    char buff[1]; // byte by byte buffer 
    inf fd = open("filename", O_RDONLY);
    
    int fdp[2]; // for the pipe's fd's
    pipe(fdp);
    
    if( fork() == 0 ) {
        close(fdp[0]);
        
    }

    else {
        write("newfile", buff, 1);
    }

}
```

for me at least at this stage this is really quite a complex question. My thinking is to read into the file descriptor the entire contents of the file then using a pipe to write byte by byte into a new file copy the entire contents of the previous file into the new file.
I am also unsure as to how lseek helps us here in this situation. Or am I over-complicating this and am in the completely wrong direction?

Comment: No, pipe won't help you. You read/write in a loop or use the `copy_file_range` linux system call

Comment: You've gotten lost somewhere in the wrong direction. There's no need for `pipe` at all here, and no need for a file descriptor. You need a simple loop. And a *full solution* is your job, not ours. It defeats the purpose of the exercise if we do all the work.

Comment: @KenWhite okay ken my bad you got offended, what would the pseudo-code look like for the loop though

Comment: 'open' is more of a 'C++' thing.
Have you considered using the C-family of functions `fopen`, `fread` and `fwrite`?
Open both files (there are functions to obtain a 'random file name), one for reading, the other for writing, read the source file into an array and write the bytes into the target file. At the end, close both files and you're done.

Comment: you see i'd have it done that same way very easily but the situation is that this case is restricting me to byte by byte.

Comment: As in 'one byte at a time'?
Well, just use `fgetc` and `fputc` then.
That's highly inefficient, but it should still work.

Comment: one of the main conditions was that you only get char `one[1]; `

Comment: `int c; while ((c = fgetc(in_fp)) != EOF) { fputc(c, out_fp); }`

Comment: My point remains the same. Please refer to https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i have it figured out the solution is actually very simple! Only about 10 lines of code or so here it is:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>



int main(int argc, char ** argv) { 
    
    char oneByte;
    
    int n;
    int source;
    int destination;
    
    source = open("notes.txt", O_RDONLY);
    destination = open("copiedFile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    
    while ((n = read(source, &oneByte, 1)) > 0) {
        write(destination, &oneByte, 1);
    }
    
    close(source);
    close(destination);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works too. Try to only include needed headers. You have no need for, e.g. `stdio.h` through `stdbool.h`. Also, since you don't use `argc` or `argv` (you should pass the filename to read as the 1st argument and the filename to write as the 2nd). Absent that, your invocation should be `int main (void)` See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated in the comments, you don't need a pipe for this at all. Honoring the 'one byte at a time' requirement, your code might look something like this:

```
FILE *in = fopen("sourceFile", "rb");
    
if (in)
{
    FILE *out = tmpfile();
    if (out)
    {
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
            fputc(c, out);
        fclose(out);
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

And you're done.
Please remember,that tmpfile will get deleted once you close it, so you may want to do something with the contents prior to closing it. Or open a more permanent file.

Comment: I appreciate your response my friend however this isn't utilizing the read/write constriction(s)

Comment: Which? That you're only reading/writing one character at a time? It does. I read one character (`c`) from the file and put it into the file. One byte at a time. If the `int` is throwing you off, we need that to detect the End of File (EOF), so we'll know when to stop reading.

Comment: Sorry if what i am saying is confusing english is my 2nd language, please see my answer to what i was reffering to the solution we have both posted work and solve this situation!

Comment: @yesitsme Yes, your solution is essentially the exact same thing as mine, except that you're using buffered reading (as in: The buffer could be any size), whereas my solution employs 'one character at a time', which cannot be changed without changing the used functions. But yes, both work.

Comment: correct but my char "oneByte" is exactly constrained to one byte because it only holds 1 character or "byte"